# Preventing automatic selecting shipping method in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Magento selects the first available shipping method by default. Our customers sometimes forget to change this option before placing the order, and later complains about the order not being delivered in the way they wanted.

To avoid this issue, we want the shipping method to remain unselected until the customer makes his choice.

After hours of trying to figure this out ourselves, we hope you can help us with the matter.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: 1.9.2.2 (we can't upgrade yet because of all the custom coding over the years)

Comment: By default all method are unselected, check with rwd or default theme

Comment: You can always add some JS code to deselect anything on page load.

Comment: No, because the page reloads on selecting shipping method. So deselecting with JS on page load would prevent the user from choosing method.

Answer (score 0):

To clear recent selection of shipping method, you need to put bellow code in this file :

```
app\design\frontend\[YOUR THEME]\template\checkout\onepage\shipping_method.phtml
```

Code:

```
$shippingaddress = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
$shippingaddress->setShippingMethod(null);
$shippingaddress->save();
```

So above code, deselect if any method selected before, So customer need to select method again.